# Android Executing Post Requests

Tags: android, apache, android-asynctask, http-post

I'm attempting to send post requests from my android app, using the apache commons library but am running into some problems, probably due to my fundamental lack of understanding of the ASyncTasks

Here is the relevant code I have written

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{
    @Override
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
        postData(params[0]);
        return null;
    }

};

    public void postData(String name) {

        //showMessage("Transaction timed out");

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // replace with your url
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://posttestserver.com/post.php");


        //Post Data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", name));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "123456789"));


        //Encoding POST data
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // log exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //making POST request.
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            // write response to log
            Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // Log exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

   public void postClick(View v)
{
    new MyAsyncTask().doInBackground("JACK");
}
```

can post the stack trace if necessary, but I am probably just doing something silly wrong, but I cant figure out why

Comment: Use     `new MyAsyncTask().execute("JACK");` to start AsyncTask instead of calling `doInBackground` as a method

Comment: AS @ρяσѕρєяK just said

Comment: you could also try Retrofit as an alternative

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK thanks prosperK as a follow up is there any simple explanation for the ASync params, I see that they mean Params, Progress and Result but dont really understand them, also feel free to post as answer and I will chose as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the: [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

AsyncTask's generic types:

The three types used by an asynchronous task are the following:

1. **Params**, the type of the parameters sent to the task upon execution.
2. **Progress**, the type of the progress units published during the background computation.
3. **Result**, the type of the result of the background computation.

Not all types are always used by an asynchronous task. To mark a type as unused, simply use the type Void:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> { ... }
```

**Usage example:**

```
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);

//This task is going to execute "downloadFile(imageHttpAddress)"
// and so it defines String as its param type - this will be sent to doInBackground(),
// it will not post any progress and so Void for progress and finally, Bitmap as its answer
            new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>(){
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();

                }

                @Override
                protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... url) {
                    return downloadFile(url[0]);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                    super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }.execute(imageHttpAddress);
    //This method takes a string (url to some image) and returns a bitmap
            private Bitmap downloadFile(String imageHttpAddress) {
                URL imageUrl = null;
                try {
                    imageUrl = new URL(imageHttpAddress);
                    HttpURLConnection conn =(HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection(); 
                    conn.connect();
                    loadedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream());
                    return loadedImage; 
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**From Documents:**
**AsyncTask** is an abstract class provided by Android which helps us to use the UI thread properly. This class allows us to perform long/background operations and show its result on the UI thread without having to manipulate threads.
AsyncTask has four steps:

**doInBackground**: Code performing long running operation goes in this method.  When onClick method is executed on click of button, it calls execute method which accepts parameters and automatically calls doInBackground method with the parameters passed.

**onPostExecute**: This method is called after doInBackground method completes processing. Result from doInBackground is passed to this method.

**onPreExecute**: This method is called before doInBackground method is called.

**onProgressUpdate**: This method is invoked by calling publish-progress anytime from doInBackground call this method.

```
 public class Restcaliing extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            ServiceHandler serviceHandler = new ServiceHandler();
            reststring = serviceHandler.makeServiceCall(prepaerdurl, ServiceHandler.POST);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + reststring, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

this my ServiceHandler Class.

```
public class ServiceHandler {

static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;

public ServiceHandler() {

}

/**
 * Making service call
 *
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
    return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
}

/**
 * Making service call
 *
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * @params - http request params
 */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method, List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        Log.d("serv handler response"," "+response);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;

}
```

}

```
  new Restcaliing().execute();
```

this how i call AsyncTask .

hope you will understand and help you.